# WinSCP command line for SSIS package

Tags: command-line, winscp, ms-sql

I am using the command line :

```
option batch on
option confirm off
open ftp:// username :password hostname:port
cd directory name ---- directory on FTP
option transfer binary
put  file name on FTP C:\Users\sshah\Desktop
close
exit
```

When I execute task it completes  without error but I do not see the file on the desktop

Any ideas what I am doing wrong>?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues I see. Are you trying to upload (use `put`) or download (use `get`) from the the FTP server?

Your statement is incorrect for a download. Also, you left off the `\` and the end of your file path - this will get you everytime.

Make sure you specify the file path on the FTP server as well, and don't for get the `/`.

You should use option bath abort. Your change directory must be with the `/`, so for example:

```
cd /IN/
```

Upload:

```
put C:\Users\sshah\Desktop\*.txt  /IN/
```

Download:

```
get /IN/*.txt on FTP C:\Users\sshah\Desktop\
```